# What is maximal rate of word `AS` in valid Oracle select statement without string literals?

Tags: sql, oracle

This question is just for fun.

```
-- Prepare scheme
CREATE USER "AS" IDENTIFIED BY 123;
ALTER USER "AS" DEFAULT TABLESPACE "USERS" QUOTA 5M ON "USERS";
CREATE TABLE "AS"."AS" ("AS" INT);

-- Now we are ready to have fun
select "AS"."AS" AS "AS" from "AS"."AS" "AS";  -- Rate = 7/9 ~ 78%
```

Can you beat this record?
String literals like `'AS'` are not allowed.

Comment: In case of dblink you could probably have: select "AS"."AS" AS "AS" from "AS"."AS"@AS "AS";  -- Rate = 8/10 ~ 80%

Comment: Also, just for fun. I'd suggest to replace AS with ASS. :)

Comment: @Marcin - Yes, it works!  `select "AS"."AS" AS "AS" from "AS"."AS"@"AS" "AS";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we can go for a lot if we do `REF` types:

```
SQL> create or replace type "AS" as object (id number, "As" ref "AS") ;
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE "as" OF "AS";

Table created.

SQL> select ("As")."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"
  2         ."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"
  3         ."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"
  4         ."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"
  5         ."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"
  6         ."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"
  7         ."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"
  8         ."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"
  9         ."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"
 10         ."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"
 11         ."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"
 12         ."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"
 13         ."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"
 14         ."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"
 15         ."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"
 16         ."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"
 17         ."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"
 18         ."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"
 19         ."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"
 20         ."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"
 21         ."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"
 22         ."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"
 23         ."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"
 24         ."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"
 25         ."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"
 26         ."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"
 27         ."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"
 28         ."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"
 29         ."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As"."As" "AS"
 30      from "as" "AS";

no rows selected
```

etc..got bored typing so many As's.

Answer (score 2):

Difficult to beat an AS density like that, but I'll go for quantity instead with a Cast(), a common table expression, a partitioned table, and a flashback query ...

```
with "as" AS (
  select cast("AS"."AS" AS integer) AS "AS"
  from  "AS"."AS" partition ("AS") "AS" AS of scn 1234567)
select "as"."as"
from   "as"
```

Might be able to slap a dblink in there as well but not sure if the syntax is valid ...

```
with "as" AS (
  select cast("AS"."AS" AS integer) AS "AS"
  from  "AS"."AS"@"AS" partition ("AS") "AS" AS of scn 1234567)
select "as"."as"
from   "as"
```